# Cookie Cannot be expired by rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I've been trying to use the rails ActionController `cookies` tool to expire a cookie that is set by a different application on the same subdomain.

Essentially a legacy app sets a cookie called "ORG_SID" that contains a UUID session_id as it's value, an expire set to "Session", etc.

[image]

In my controller I've tried:

```
cookies.delete('ORG_SID', domain: :all)

cookes['ORG_SID'] = {:expires  => Time.at(0), :domain => :all}
```

I've also tried the exact subdomain of the cookie as well as the TLD of the cookie as inputs to domain.

In each case the cookie is unmodified, by the controllers actions.

Comment: How are you creating the cookie? Can you show us that as well?

Comment: yeah seeing how you are setting the cookie might be helpful.. also I am sure you already checked this but the name of the cookie when deleting is case sensitive.